# Devise Reset password token can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to debut the error "Reset password token can't be blank" in my rails app when trying to reset a password. I've received an email in my console with a link to reset my password. When I pull up the link and enter my new password, I get the error "Reset password token can't be blank"

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it? I'm using [devise-basecamper](https://github.com/digitalopera/devise-basecamper) gem as well

Let me know if there's anything else I can post that is helpful.

```
Started GET "/users/password/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-08 22:43:09 -0600
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#new as HTML
  Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`subdomain` = 'mysubdomain' LIMIT 1
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`account_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `applicants` WHERE `applicants`.`company_id` = 1 AND (viewed = false and archived = false and submitted = true)
  Rendered devise/passwords/new.html.erb within layouts/session (17.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 808ms (Views: 309.2ms | ActiveRecord: 44.8ms)
Wed, 15 Jan 2014 19:04:50 CST -06:00
Wed, 08 Jan 2014 22:43:17 CST -06:00


Started POST "/users/password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-08 22:43:17 -0600
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"96PTbxVrxaQWiXh6QXGZUyRe/7J/lLQo4hbASED1Mrs=", "user"=>{"email"=>"support@example.com", "subdomain"=>"mysubdomain"}, "submit"=>"Send me reset password instructions"}
  Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`subdomain` = 'mysubdomain' LIMIT 1
  Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`account_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `applicants` WHERE `applicants`.`company_id` = 1 AND (viewed = false and archived = false and submitted = true)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`subdomain` = 'mysubdomain' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`account_id` = 1 AND `users`.`email` = 'support@example.com' LIMIT 1
  Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb (23.9ms)

Sent mail to support@example.com (32ms)
Date: Wed, 08 Jan 2014 22:43:18 -0600
From: support@example.com
Reply-To: support@example.com
To: support@example.com
Message-ID: <52ce28e64d967_87e73fda575bea4889930@Toms-Mac-mini.local.mail>
Subject: Reset password instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Hello support@example.com!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password, and you can do this through the link below.</p>

<p><a href="http://mysubdomain.127.0.0.1.xip.io:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=wHnYjLtLtXfU8FButP3p">Change my password</a></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>

Redirected to http://mysubdomain.127.0.0.1.xip.io:3000/login
Completed 302 Found in 536ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Wed, 15 Jan 2014 19:04:50 CST -06:00
Wed, 08 Jan 2014 22:43:18 CST -06:00


Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-08 22:43:18 -0600
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`subdomain` = 'mysubdomain' LIMIT 1
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`account_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `applicants` WHERE `applicants`.`company_id` = 1 AND (viewed = false and archived = false and submitted = true)
  Rendered shared/_messages.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/session (13.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 22.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
Wed, 15 Jan 2014 19:04:50 CST -06:00
Wed, 08 Jan 2014 22:43:28 CST -06:00


Started GET "/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=[FILTERED]" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-08 22:43:28 -0600
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]"}
  Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`subdomain` = 'mysubdomain' LIMIT 1
  Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`account_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `applicants` WHERE `applicants`.`company_id` = 1 AND (viewed = false and archived = false and submitted = true)
  Rendered devise/passwords/edit.html.erb within layouts/session (1.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 36ms (Views: 29.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
Wed, 15 Jan 2014 19:04:50 CST -06:00
Wed, 08 Jan 2014 22:43:39 CST -06:00


Started PUT "/users/password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-08 22:43:39 -0600
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"96PTbxVrxaQWiXh6QXGZUyRe/7J/lLQo4hbASED1Mrs=", "user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "submit"=>"Change my Password"}
  Account Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`subdomain` = 'mysubdomain' LIMIT 1
  Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`account_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `applicants` WHERE `applicants`.`company_id` = 1 AND (viewed = false and archived = false and submitted = true)
  Rendered devise/passwords/edit.html.erb within layouts/session (2.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 39ms (Views: 27.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: please share the user model.

Comment: Is the app brand new or upgraded from Rails 3 to 4? It may be a strong parameters issue or some stale Devise configuration.

Comment: Dude, did you get a link like this,  http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=GVN7DnKTVVsE15gMXaFb, see the reset_password_token in the query parameter?? Also in your set password page, make sure you have line like this.. <input class="hidden" id="user_reset_password_token" name="user[reset_password_token]" type="hidden" value="GVN7DnKTVVsE15gMXaFb" />

Comment: @beck03076 I see that the devise view is missing that hidden field. I looked in my git repo and see that that file used to contain that hidden field, but I must have deleted it. Can you post your solution as answer and I'll test to make sure that is truly the reason?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you get a link like this?

http://localhost.com/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=GVN7DnKTVVsE15gMXaFb
(remove .com)

See the reset_password_token in the query parameter?

Also in your set password page, make sure you have line like this

```
<input class="hidden" id="user_reset_password_token" name="user[reset_password_token]" type="hidden" value="GVN7DnKTVVsE15gMXaFb" />
```

Comment: Yes, line should look like this
<%= f.hidden_field :reset_password_token %>